# Umake - permission denied when installing outside home directory (even as root)

Tags: permissions, python, ubuntu-make

I'm trying to install firefox-dev using umake. By default the umake install path is `~/.local/share/`; I'd rather it was in `/usr/local/` or `/opt/`.

The problem appears to be umake (or, rather, the os.py script it runs) not having permission to create files/directories - this happens even when I'm running as an admin user elevated using `sudo`, or I've switched to the root user using `sudo -i`.

Here's an example of the relevant error:

```
    os.makedirs(self.install_path, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/umake'
```

Is there any way to install binaries using umake outside of the /home/ directories?

**Edit:** Nothing unusual in the command run - `sudo umake web firefox-dev`. Does not matter where I run it.

As for install paths (entered into the prompt during install attempts), I've once again tried all options from explicitly declared absolute paths (including creating the dirtree myself, which ultimately and unsurprisingly just pushes the error messages back to file creation) to being in the target dir and using './'.

I have absolutely no problems doing anything as root myself, but those permissions don't seem to be being inherited by the python install script(s).

Comment: please can i see the __installation command__ you used and in what directory was it done.

Comment: No bother - see my edit.

Comment: I am thinking _umake_ was not designed to install outside the `/home` dir but let keep looking

Comment: I had wondered that, but if so that makes it almost useless for my purposes. I know it definitely used to be possible - there's someone with the exact same question on here from a few years ago, but in that case the problem was the user wasn't running anything as root; as soon as they used `sudo` they were able to install where they wanted. I'll probably just give up and use the PPA or manually copy the binary over as this really isn't worth the time it's taking to troubleshoot - I only tried using it because it looked more convenient.

Comment: best of luck then :), but if I see something will drop it here.

Comment: Cheers man , much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, turns out this is a (pretty long-standing) [issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/79) with Ubuntu Make.

There are a couple of workarounds suggested by one of the devs in the above link.

First (preferred) solution:

```
sudo -s
unset SUDO_UID
unset SUDO_GID
```

Then run `umake` to install your application as normal - you should now be able to install to any directory you want. Works flawlessly.

The second option is to create the desired installation folder beforehand and set permissions for the install directory so it can be written by non-root users, but I experienced issues using this with some applications even when permissions were applied recursively and `umake` was executed using `sudo`. I'd stick to the first method.

Comment: After doing the umake installation, specifically for android-studio, did you run the installation script in the same sudo shell? eg, ```/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh```

Comment: One can do everything in one command, like this: `sudo env -u SUDO_UID -u SUDO_GID umake web firefox-dev /usr/local/firefox-dev/`